# How can I use my Stack Exchange profile image on Data Explorer?

Tags: support, profile-page, data-explorer, profile-picture

On all of the Stack Exchange sites, I have my own profile picture, not the default image. However, on Data Explorer, I cannot change the picture. It redirects me to http://en.gravatar.com. So how do I use my Stack Exchange picture on Data Explorer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently Data Explorer only supports gravatar, so the short answer is that you don't (unless you already use gravar, in which case you'd just set your email accordingly).

There are some improvements that are on my todo list though that will likely change this, though. I've just been strapped for time lately, but hopefully that'll change soon.

Comment: So I'm stuck with the boring old image...